# How to clearly visualise counts of multiple categories that sum to the same value

Tags: r, data-visualization

This is a data visualisation question based on the following:

Participants were asked to think of their 5 closest friends. They then
categorised these friends based on which football team the friends
supported. Specifically, participants were asked how many of these 5
friends support the same team, a different team, or no team. The total
had to equal 5. For example, a participant could have responded with 3
friends support the same team, 1 friend supports a different team, and
1 friend supports no team.

One option is to generate a bar plot (see below). The problem with this
is that it does not show how the categories are related. Participants
with 3 friends who support the same team could have either 2 friends
who support a different team, 2 friends who support no team, or 1
friend who supports a different team and 1 friend who supports no
team.

Here are some data. I plot in R using tidyverse/ggplot2 --- although
visualisations created in other packages/languages are welcome!

```r
## load required packages
library(tidyverse) # tidyverse v 1.2.1 with ggplot2 v 3.2.0
## set seed
set.seed(500)

## create tibble with randomly generated data
data <-
    tibble(id = 1:20,
           ## column with friends who support same team
           same = round(runif(20, 0, 5), 0),
           ## column with friends who support different team
           diff = round(runif(20, 0, 5 - same), 0),
           ## column with friends who support no team
           none = 5 - (same + diff),
           ## column that checks total equals 5
           total = if_else(same + diff + none == 5, TRUE, FALSE))

## create plot
data %>%
    gather(friends, number, c("same", "diff", "none")) %>%
    ggplot() + 
    geom_bar(aes(x = number, fill = friends),
             stat = "count",
             ## preserve to not drop counts of 0 
             position = position_dodge(preserve = "single")) +
    ## set axes to make plot more legible
    scale_x_discrete(limits = c(0:5)) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 20, 1)) +
    theme_classic()
```

I am unaware of any standard way of visualising such data, so any
pointers would be greatly appreciated!

[image: bar-plot-of-friends-by-which-team-they-support]

Comment: Would Sankey diagrams come handy here? https://plot.ly/r/sankey-diagram/

Comment: Nice suggestion, thanks @RomanLuštrik! I'll have a go at making one to see if it works.

Answer (score 4):

You could try mosaic plots.  This does not use any packages.

```
tab <- as.matrix(data[2:4])
rownames(tab) <- data$id
mosaicplot(tab, col = rainbow(3), main = "My Plot")
```

[image: screenshot]

### ggmosaic

The ggmosaic package provides `geom_mosaic` if you want a ggplot2 version.

```
library(ggmosaic)

data %>%
  gather(friends, number, c("same", "diff", "none")) %>%
  ggplot() + 
    geom_mosaic(aes(weight = number, x = product(friends), 
      conds = product(id), fill = friends))
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have three alternatives,  another option might be a [ternary plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_plot).

```
library(vcd)
ternaryplot(data[,2:4])
```

[image: ternary plot]

Of course, some of your points overlap,  so it may be helpful to apply jitter.

```
ternaryplot(abs(apply(data[,2:4], 2, jitter)), cex=0.8)
```

[image: ternary plot with jitter]

Comment: This is a nice alternative. For anyone interested, the package `ggtern` is also available. Some code: 

`library(ggtern)

data %>%
    ggtern(aes(x = same, y = diff, z = none)) +
    geom_mask() +
    geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
    theme_bw()`